# Edit item in react with graphql

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, crud

I want to create a crud app with `react` and `grapgql`(my problem is for update section). I have a list of `todos` and when I click on edit button it is gone to edit page.

**problem:** I want to see the `todo title` when I go to edit page (but it doesn't show `todo title` in the field.it's just show an empty input field) and then after editing item navigate to home page. Thank you for your help

my components:

**Todos.js**:

```
const Todos = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_TODOS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading ... </p>
  if (error) return <p>Something went wrong!</p>

  return (
    <>
      {!loading && !error && (
        <div>
          {data.todos.map(todo => (
            <Todo todo={todo} key={todo.id}/>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

**Todo.js**:

```
const Todo = ({ todo }) => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div>
      <button  onClick={() => navigate(`/edit/${todo.id}`)}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </div>
 )
```

**EditTodo.js:**

```
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
  const { id } = useParams();

  const { data } = useQuery(GET_TODO, {
    variables: { id }
  });

  const [editTodo] = useMutation(EDIT_TODO, {
    variables: { id },
    refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_TODOS, variables: { id } }]
  })


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
     editTodo(title);
    // navigate('/')
  }

  return (
    <>
    
      {data.todo.title}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <div>
            <input
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
              required
              type="text" placeholder="Name" />
          </div>
          <div >
            <button>
              Edit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
```

**Queries & mutatation:**

```
const GET_TODOS = gql`
  query getTodos {
   todos{
     id
     title
    }
  }
`;

const GET_TODO = gql`
  query getTodo($id:ID!){
    todo(id:$id){
     id 
     title
    }
  }
`;
const EDIT_TODO = gql`
  mutation EditTodo($id: ID! $title: String!) {
    EditTodo(id: $id title: $title) {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution :adding a `useEffect`, here is `EditTodo.js` file

```
const EditTodo = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { data } = useQuery(GET_TODO, {
    variables: { id }
  });
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(data){
      setTitle(data.todo.title || "")
    }
  },[data])


  const [editTodo] = useMutation(EDIT_TODO, {
    variables: { id, title },
    refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_TODOS, variables: { id } }]
  })


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    editTodo(title);
    navigate('/')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see in your code is that you are not setting the initial value of the title state in your ***EditTodo.js*** component. You can do this by adding a **useEffect** hook that sets the title state to the value of ***data.todo.title*** when the component mounts or when ***data.todo.title*** changes. Refer Below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (data && data.todo) {
    setTitle(data.todo.title);
  }
}, [data]);
```

Above code should set the initial value of the title state to the current todo title, which will then be displayed in the input field.

To navigate back to the home page after editing a to-do item. You can do this by calling the navigate function after calling **editTodo**. Refer Below:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  editTodo({
    variables: {
      id,
      title
    }
  });
  navigate('/');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I find the answer and post it above.